# Java persistence api don't want to create entities

Tags: java, jpa

Is there any way to use JPA just for insert, update, delete and select but not to change tables?  I have made a reverse engineering and made java classes from database tables... In this class I have    @Entity and @Id annotations, but I don't need to create entities or fields in the database. I have a finished database schema and there is a DB Admin who is responsible for all tables and fields. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean not create entities? The java classes you created are the entities. If you dont want to map them to the database, you would need to use raw SQL to achieve that. The point of mapping the classes to the tables is having the data access layer decoupled for the DB engine, using raw SQL couples it tightly. Or maybe i misunderstood something xD.

Comment: Creating an entity means inserting a row in the database; you seem to think that it means adding a new table in the database.

Comment: When i make a change in the class , this change will be affected in the database. When the database Admin make a change in the database, this change will not automatically change my class. Is that a problem? I have worked on a object database and this way of changing database schema make a big in the database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean that you don't want to create/modify any table... Turn off ddl schema generation in persistence.xml

Comment: Right answer... Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an EntityManagerFactory object to realize your operations(insert, delete......) and call your functions in main. 
It need you to import javax.persistence.*

Answer (score 0):

It is up to the developer whether to create new entities (rows in a table).  There is no specific ORM technology for the above scenarios. Creating tables in a database is an additional feature provided by the most of the technologies, providing entities.  In this case, you can create respective entity object from the database (as you already have the database) and then insert a new row, update, delete and free to do what ever you want.

Thanks,
JK